# Python operator != isn't working as expected

Tags: python, operators, not-operator

Does anyone know why this sample is not working? I have not used Python in years and wanted to test NOT operators. As far as I can remember this should work, I have checked online and it appears to be the correct format. Am I missing something?

Essentially it is just asking for an input of 1, 2 or 3. If the user enters those it will break out the loop. If they do not enter either 1, 2 or 3 it will print to screen and loop again. Currently it is only printing "Invalid input!" then looping not breaking.

```
while True:
    x = input("1, 2, or 3?\n")
    if x != 1 or x != 2 or x != 3:
        print("Invalid input!")
    else:
        break
```

I am using Python 3.6.4.

Comment: Well `x != 1 or x != 2` is always going to be `True`.

Comment: `1 != '1'` Strings are not integers. This is in addition to the logic error that other have pointed out.

Comment: Run through the logic yourself -- when the user enters `1`, then `x != 2` is `True`, and because you're using `or`, it's treated as invalid.  Probably you want to be using `and`.

Comment: You have a *type* problem (inputs are strings, not integers) **and** a *logic* problem (there's no value of `x`, barring weird custom objects, for which `x != 1 or x != 2 or x != 3` would ever be false).

Comment: Thanks all! i thought it could have been data type so had played around with both ints / strings. Somehow i didnt think it through with and rather than or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this will be always true. if I type `1`, it'll fail the first condition, but it'll pass the other two: `x != 2 or x != 3`. Any other number different than 1, 2 or 3 will also be `true` for all the conditions. There's no problem with the comparison operator.

I think you want to do something like:

```
x = int(input("1, 2, or 3?\n"))
if x not in [1, 2, 3]:
    print("Invalid input!")
```

The conversion of `x` to `int` is also important. Otherwise, the comparison of `x` with the numbers will be always `false`.